# Performance issue when setting the currentState twice

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, state

When i set the currentState of a component twice with the same value, like this:

```
component.currentState = "stateName";
component.currentState = "stateName";
```

does it apply the state twice, or does it see that at the second time its given the same state as it currently is and just does nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just checked the source code for UIComponent, and it says that it only applies the state if its different from the currentState.